# Computed column for between values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, calculated-columns

I have a table PERSON in which I have two columns(of course I have others but here I just needed two) named `Age` and `Person_Type`. Now based on the `Age` Value I have to make `Person_Type` as Infant, Child and Adult.

```
Age    Person_Type
0 to 3     Infant
4 to 12    Child
>=13    Adult
```

I have tried below in computed column but it is not working. Any Idea how to do? I am so much confused.

```
(case when [Pax_Type_Id]=(3) OR [Pax_Type_Id]=(2) OR [Pax_Type_Id]=(1) OR [Pax_Type_Id]=(0) then 'Infant' when [Pax_Type_Id]=(12) OR [Pax_Type_Id]=(11) OR [Pax_Type_Id]=(10) OR [Pax_Type_Id]=(9) OR [Pax_Type_Id]=(8) OR [Pax_Type_Id]=(7) OR [Pax_Type_Id]=(6) OR [Pax_Type_Id]=(5) OR [Pax_Type_Id]=(4) then 'Child' when [Pax_Type_Id]>=(13) then 'Adult'  end)
```

Comment: What is Pax_Type_Id? SHould not be there Age?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
SELECT AGE, CASE WHEN AGE BETWEEN '1' AND '3' THEN 'INFANT'
            WHEN AGE BETWEEN '4' AND '12' THEN  'CHILD'
            WHEN AGE >='13' THEN 'ADULT' ELSE '' END PERSON_TYPE
 FROM PERSON
```

Comment: I am not getting what you are asking.

Comment: I was asking , are you using the same column values for the column AGE which you have mentioned in your question ?

Comment: Thanks . It helped. Just change between '1' and '3' to between '0' and '3'

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 0 AND 3 THEN 'Infant'
         WHEN Age BETWEEN 4 AND 12 THEN 'Child'
         WHEN Age >=13 THEN 'Adult'
       END AS Person_type
FROM PERSON
```